# create docker-compose file from Dockerfile

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have this simple Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:boron

# Create app directory
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install app dependencies
COPY package.json /usr/src/app/
RUN npm install

# Bundle app source
COPY . /usr/src/app

EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

I would like to use docker-compose so that I can simply say `docker-compose up` or `docker-compose down`.

I am struggling to find a simple docker-compose example of how I would use `docker-compose`, all I can find are examples like [this](http://anandmanisankar.com/posts/docker-container-nginx-node-redis-example/) which cover more ground than I need.

How could I create a simple docker-compose file from the above?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You write following in `docker-compose.yml` file to run your docker container using compose:

```
version: '3'

services:
  app:
    build: .
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
```

Docker compose file is made of multiple services but in your case it is enough to define one service. `build` option specifies from where to pick up the Dockerfile to build the image and `ports` will allow port forwarding from the container to you host OS.

To start the service you can use:

```
docker-compose up
```

And to stop the service:

```
docker-compose down
```

You can find more documentation about the compose file [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/)